# RTF String Font Size

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I am a little confused with the `RichTextBox.Rtf` property. I am inputting a string with a mix of font sizes: `Test` with font size of 20 and `string` as font size of 10. However when I look at the `Rtf` string, I get the following:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard**\fs40 Test\fs20 string**\fs20\par\r\n}\r\n

That suggests the font size is 40 and 20 - can anyone tell me why they differ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [RTF specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_20):

> \fsN Font size in half-points (the default is 24).

Which matches your observation...